# Get char before Substring in bash

Tags: bash

i try to get the char before a substring in bash.
Some examples of the String:

```
label="LLL:EXT:xxx/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:flux.content"
```

or:

```
label='LLL:EXT:xxx/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:flux.content'
```

or:

```
$this->getLanguageService()->sL('LLL:EXT:xxx/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:flux.content'
```

i need to know if there is a single- or doublequote before the LLL. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking whether or not there is a `'` or `"` before `LLL`. The shortest answer would be `grep -q "['\"]LLL"`.

If the exit code is `0`, then the answer is yes, if the exit code is `1`, then the answer is no.

For example:

```
$ echo 'label="LLL:EXT:xxx/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:flux.content"' | grep -q "['\"]LLL"
$ echo $?
0
```

```
$ echo test | grep -q "['\"]LLL"
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: This is how i also solved it short time ago. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the character using pure Bash code with:

```
[[ $string =~ (.)LLL ]] && char=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

See the sections on [[[...]]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b) and [BASH_REMATCH](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-BASH_005fREMATCH) in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep for this.

```
grep -E -o '.{0,1}LLL' file
grep -E -o '.{0,1}LLL' file | cut -c-1 # shows only the first character
```

- -E indicates the pattern is an extended regular expression
- -o shows only the matching portion
- '.{0,1}LLL' specifies the pattern with the first preceding character appended